# What do you call an example/statement/question etc. presented just for the sake of demonstration/argument?

Tags: meaning

Like when you say something as an example. Like a hypothetical situation that may/may not be practical or technically not true but just there for the purpose of demonstration?

- By the help of wormholes you can travel faster than light.
- Popular belief is that he could cause sparks of fire/lightning just by the snapping his thumb and index fingers.

I know about rhetorical questions (ones that are asked for the sake of argument and are not expected to be answered). So can there be something like *rhetorical statement/example*? Also can rhetorical questions be used in the context of irony? Feel free to correct me. :)

Comment: I think you answered your own question with *hypothetical*.

Comment: @psosuna Shouldn't rhetorical be the word? I thought hypothetical only applied to scientific scenarios.

Comment: I don’t think *rhetoric* describes your examples well. You may need to provide more context to show what effect the speaker was trying to achieve, and how the quoted part helped achieve that.

Comment: You could consider ***thought experiment***.

Comment: Thanks for your input , your suggestions  have been duly noted.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I should give a proper answer to explain my comment.

From [Oxford Dictionaries:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hypothetical)

> ***hypothetical***
>   *adjective*
>
> 1. Based on or serving as a hypothesis.
>      *let us take a hypothetical case*
>      1.1 Supposed but not necessarily real or true.
>      *the hypothetical tenth planet*
>      1.2 *Logic* Denoting or containing a proposition of the logical form if p then q.

I think the definition you're looking for is then 1.1, *Supposed but not necessarily real or true.* Here, there's no mention of said hypothesis needing to be rooted in science or the scientific method.

Comment: I understand,  I'm just finding it a bit awkward to use 'hypothetical' to describe an example present in  colliqual/trivial scenario.